# when $x<0$, I have trouble with handling $mx^a$ because it can be complex number

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

when $x<0$, I have trouble with handling $mx^a$ because it can be complex number. even if $mx^a$ is a real number, I can't handle this because I don't know how to use properties of powers when $x<0$. please help me...

Comment: Better to write out the problem here, than to ask users to go offsite to find it. If you're having trouble formatting math on this site, there's help available via the Help menu.

Comment: The problem should probably have said "just worry about nonnegative $x$" in some way.